# Can't access my /movie/:id route in react router others are working fine. can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I didn't want my navbar in login and signup pages so i find this solution and it works well.

but in default container I can't access /movie/:id. it always redirects to home component. other paths are working fine.

and also, whenever i try to refresh pages in `defaultconainer` it goes to home component.
here is my `main.js` file. please help me correct this small errors.

```
const LoginContainer = () => (
<div>
  <Route path="/login" component={Signin} />
</div>
);

const SignupContainer = () => (
<div>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
</div>
);

const DefaultContainer = () => (
<div>
    <Header />
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <SecuredRoute path='/profile' component={Profile} />
    <Route path='/movies' component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path='/movie/:Id' component={MovieDetail} />
    <Redirect to={Home} />
</div>
);

class Main extends Component {

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupContainer}/>
                <Route component={DefaultContainer}/>  
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Switch` container to wrap your `DefaultContainer Routes`, otherwise all matching Routes will be executed which also indicates that regardless of what other Routes match, Redirect will always be executed causing the page to redirect to Home

However, when you use Switch container, you would need to restructure the order of your Routes so that prefix routes are at the end

```js
const DefaultContainer = () => (
  <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <SecuredRoute path='/profile' component={Profile} />
          <Route path='/movie/:Id' component={MovieDetail} />
          <Route path='/movies' component={LandingPage} />
          <Redirect to={Home} />
      </Switch>
  </div>
);
```